# Does the NDB membership query ("IN" operation) performance degrade with lots of possible values?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) for the `IN` query operation states that those queries are implemented as a big OR'ed equality query:

```python
qry = Article.query(Article.tags.IN(['python', 'ruby', 'php']))
```

is equivalent to:

```python
qry = Article.query(ndb.OR(Article.tags == 'python',
                           Article.tags == 'ruby',
                           Article.tags == 'php'))
```

I am currently modelling some entities for a GAE project and plan on using these membership queries with a lot of possible values:

```python
qry = Player.query(Player.facebook_id.IN(list_of_facebook_ids))
```

where `list_of_facebook_ids` could have thousands of items.

Will this type of query perform well with thousands of possible values in the list? If not, what would be the recommended approach for modelling this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't work with thousands of values (in fact I bet it starts degrading with more than 10 values).  The only alternative I can think of are some form of precomputation.  You'll have to change your schema.

Comment: Thanks. I am thinking about using 'facebook_id' as the key for my entities, and using ndb.get_multi() to fetch all the entities that are in my list of possible values. Would that work?

Comment: get_multi() definitely works fine with hundreds of keys; I'd be hesitant with thousands although if the entities are small or you expect many of these to be non-existent you may be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do a "keys only" get_multi()? I'm really not that interested in fetching the whole entities, I just want to answer the question "among this list of keys, which are present in the data store?". Is there something tailored to this sort of query?

Comment: No, we don't have that feature.  If your entities are big, consider breaking them in two: a lightweight summary and an optional part containing the rarer-used, larger properties.  You could make the latter a child of the former, so you can read and write them atomically.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can you do it is to create a new model called FacebookPlayer which is an index. This would be keyed by facebook_id. You would update it whenever you add a new player. It looks something like this:

```
class FacebookUser(ndb.Model):
    player = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Player', required=True)
```

Now you can avoid queries altogether. You can do this:

```
# Build keys from facebook ids.
facebook_id_keys = []
for facebook_id in list_of_facebook_ids:
    facebook_id_keys.append(ndb.Key('FacebookPlayer', facebook_id))

keysOfUsersMatchedByFacebookId = []
for facebook_player in ndb.get_multi(facebook_id_keys):
    if facebook_player:
        keysOfUsersMatchedByFacebookId.append(facebook_player.player)
usersMatchedByFacebookId = ndb.get_multi(keysOfUsersMatchedByFacebookId)
```

If list_of_facebook_ids is thousands of items, you should do this in batches.