# Ordering a query

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, datastore

This set of queries below concatenate a bunch of profiles together to be returned to a website.

I would like to make one query with these because I would like to use the order function on the entire collection of profiles.

```
# Get all users for who 'currentUser' is an assistant for.
users = Users.query(Users.assistant.IN(currentUser)).fetch()

# Get all profiles that belong to those users and have not been deleted.
for user in users:
    profiles = profiles + Profiles.query(
            ndb.AND(
            Profiles.user == user.username,
            Profiles.deleted == False
        )
    ).order(Profiles.history).fetch() # Order all profiles by timestamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for would be, in a way, equivalent to:

```
# get the list of usernames obtained above
usernames = [user.username for user in users]

profiles = Profiles.query(ndb.AND(Profiles.user.IN(usernames),
                                  Profiles.deleted == False))
                         .order(Profiles.history).fetch()
```

But this will have performance issues if `usernames` contains many elements (apparently over 10 or so), see [Does the NDB membership query ("IN" operation) performance degrade with lots of possible values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936035/does-the-ndb-membership-query-in-operation-performance-degrade-with-lots-of).